# How do I get Minecraft-pi Python API running using apt-get?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, minecraft

There are many sites that describe how to get Minecraft-pi (and its API) up and running on a Raspberry pi using downloaded tar.gz, e.g.,

[pi.minecraft.net](http://pi.minecraft.net/?page_id=10)

[www.raspberrpi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/minecraft/) (this site is close, but missing some details a newbie might need)

but how do I install using apt-get, and then get the API up and running?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Minecraft-pi using apt-get. This installs Minecraft-pi to `/opt/minecraft-pi`

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-pi`

2. Install the Minecraft-pi API. This installs the API as a package to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

`cd /opt/minecraft-pi/api/python
sudo python setup.py install`

3. Ready to use the API - example imports below, customize as needed for your project

`sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mcpi")
from mcpi.block import *
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
from mcpi.vec3 import Vec3`